# Pivoting columns based on nearest date value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Not sure if I explain title correctly but here is teh scnerio. I have this table
[image]

i want to show results as :

[image]

For corresponding TS value CS and SCS values are picked as where the date value for CS or SCS are nearest less or equal to values date value for TS.If not found then these values(CS,SCS) should be null.
Thanks.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?  What have you tried thus far?

Comment: sql server 2008 r2. I am using temp tables and storing those value (CS,SCS and more) on different table then joining based on values. its uses many temp tables to get results. I need simple solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach uses correlated subqueries:

```
select t.id, t.date, t.name,
       (select top 1 startvalue
        from table t2
        where t2.date <= t.date and
              t2.name = 'cs'
        order by t2.date desc
       ) as cs,
       (select top 1 startvalue
        from table t2
        where t2.date <= t.date and
              t2.name = 'scs'
        order by t2.date desc
       ) as scs
from table t
where t.name = 'TS';
```

You can do something very similar using `outer apply`.